# Calling a method from another class error Java

Tags: java, eclipse, actionlistener

I am trying to access a method in another class from ActionListener in another class however, nameWelcome in the ActionListener has a syntax error message asking me to create a variable of it. I have already created an object and referring it to the class that I want to access. I don't know where I am making a mistake:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mathMulti extends JFrame {
    JButton nextButton;
    TextField nameField;
    JLabel fullName;
    JFrame frameOne;
    JPanel panelOne;

    public mathMulti() {

        frameStart();

    }

    public void frameStart() {


        frameOne = new JFrame();
        frameOne.setSize(500, 500);
        frameOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panelOne = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panelOne.setBackground(Color.gray);
        frameOne.add(panelOne);

        GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
        fullName = new JLabel("Full Name: ");
        g.insets = new Insets(-390, -195, 0, 0);
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 0;
        panelOne.add(fullName, g);

        nameField = new TextField(30);
        g.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        g.gridx = 1;
        g.gridy = 0;
        g.weightx = 0;
        g.weighty = 0;
        g.ipady = 6;
        panelOne.add(nameField, g);

        nextButton = new JButton(" NEXT " + '\u25BA');
        g.insets = new Insets(60, 5, 5, 5);
        g.gridx = 2;
        g.gridy = 5;
        g.weightx = 0;
        g.weighty = 0;

        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

               mathApo mathA =  new mathApo();
               mathA.frameNext();
               nameWelcome.setText(nameField.getText());
               frameOne.dispose();

            }

        });

        panelOne.add(nextButton, g);

        frameOne.setVisible(true);

    }


    public class mathApo extends JFrame {

          JFrame frameTwo;
          JPanel panelTwo;
          JLabel nameWelcome;

        public mathApo() {

            frameNext();

        }

        public void frameNext() {

            frameTwo = new JFrame();
            frameTwo.setSize(500, 500);
            frameTwo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            panelTwo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panelTwo.setBackground(Color.gray);
            frameTwo.add(panelTwo);

            nameWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome, ");
            panelTwo.add(nameWelcome);

            frameTwo.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: nameWelcome is in mathApo and you call it like it isn't. mathA.nameWelcome.setText(nameField.getText());

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: It is Java convention to have the first letter of classes capitalized. It's not a big deal, but instead of `mathApo`, it's more common to do `MathApo`.

Answer (score 0):

Like user Worthless pointed out in a comment, you're calling the variable `nameWelcome` like it is a field in your `mathMulti` class, but really it's a field in your `mathApo` class.

So this:

```
nameWelcome.setText(nameField.getText());
```

should really be:

```
mathA.nameWelcome.setText(nameField.getText());
```

Also, even though it isn't super important, it's convention in Java to capitalize the first letter of a class name. So instead of `mathApo` and `mathMulti`, it would be `MathApo` and `MathMulti`.